# Is there another way to handle navigation in React apps without using NavLink element in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby={`navbarDropdown${index}`}>
    {navItem.dropdownItems.map((item, subindex) => (
        <NavLink 
            className="dropdown-item"
            key={subindex}
            to={`/${navItem.path}${typeof item.path === 'string' ? '/' + item.name.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase() : item.path}`}
            onClick={handleAddNewClientClick(item.path)}
        >
            {typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.name}
        </NavLink>
    ))}
</div>
```

This NavLink has a click event handler and also the "to" attribute that stores the navigation path to the dropdown menu item. I have also included a screenshot[handleAddNewClientClick()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRQuO.png) of the code in the  handleAddNewClientClick(item.path) function.

when the NavLink element is clicked; the click event handler is fired first then the page navigates to item.path (which is this: "http://localhost:3000/addnewclient"). However, you can see that even though this url has the localhost:3000 attachment it doesnt show that /addnewclient is a subdirectory of /clientservices/ like this "http://localhost:3000/clientservices/addnewclient". Also, right after this happens, the "to" attribute of the NavLink element is also triggered and this sends the page to a defective url, ie: "http://clientservices/addnewclient" as you can see, this url isn't attached to the localhost:3000 which is where the app is running currently.

Comment: Why does NavLink need an onClick handler?